# Google Play only shows app name in subscriptions list

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

My app has several subscription types, **but** when I go to `Account > Subscriptions` in Google Play app, I only manage to see **app name** as a subscription list entry, not the corresponding subscription name.

[image]

So, it gets really hard to recognize which subscription it is. For example in order to cancel one.

I've checked the dev console, and the names of the subscription are correct. And, when I go to `Account > Order History` or just the app page on Google play, the subscription titles are shown correctly as well:

[image]
[image]

So **the question**: can I manage somehow the title of subscription via my app code or dev console, or it's totally related to the implementation of Google Play?

Comment: This is probably dumb suggestion being that you explored the situation already, but did you configure the subscription title correctly as seen [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html#administering)? I only ask because you said you checked the subscription **name**.

Comment: Yes by name I meant title actually. And it is a required field, so you're not able to add a subscription without a title

Comment: The pictures inside of question is not shown. Can you update it.

Comment: @rom4ek Thanks for you report. We are aware about this poor UX and we are already working on a redesign for the subscription center. I'll update this question with further instructions when it's live. Thanks.

Comment: @NetoMarin thank you! Looking forward to your updates.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the subscription list in Google Payments Page at https://pay.google.com where all kinds of payment activity and all subscriptions will be listed.

And, No, you can't use Play Console API or your code to check the subscription. However, the developer can access it using code.

Answer (score 0):

Google Play now offers more details from the app, when go to > `Payments & subscriptions` > `Subscriptions`  > (Click on the app) > `Manage subscription`

Now you will see the name of `Plan`

[image: screen]